# Oracle SQL Developer Create View Assignment

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I've got an assignment with the following instructions:

Create a view named A11T1 (that's A-One-One-T-One, not A-L-L-T-L) that will display the concatenated name, JobTitle and Salary of the people who have a Cat value of N and whose salary is at least 30 percent higher than the average salary of all people who have a Cat value of N. The three column headings should be Name, JobTitle and Salary. The rows should be sorted in traditional phonebook order.

Note 1: As always, concatenated names must appear with one space between the first and last names.

Note 2: The concatenated names and job titles must be displayed in proper case (e.g., Mary Ellen Smith, Assistant Manager) for this task.

Note 3: Remember, the Person11 data is messy. Be sure to look for N and n when you are identifying the people with a Cat value of N.

What I have so far is:

```
CREATE VIEW A11T1 AS 
SELECT INITCAP(FNAME||' '||LNAME) AS "Name", INITCAP(JobTitle), Salary
FROM PERSON11
WHERE UPPER(CAT) = 'N'
GROUP by INITCAP(FNAME||' '||LNAME), INITCAP(JobTitle), Salary
HAVING SALARY >= 1.3 * ROUND(AVG(SALARY),0)
Order by LNAME, FNAME
```

> Error at Command Line:7 Column:10 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 00979. 00000 - "not a GROUP BY expression"

Is the current error I'm getting

No matter how much I edit my code it just won't create into a view and I've been stuck on this for hours! I appreciate any responses, even a point in the right direction.

Comment: I don't know about views in Oracle, but in sql-server views can't have an order-by clause. What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Error at Command Line:7 Column:10
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Is the current error I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way uses window functions:

```
CREATE VIEW A11T1 AS 
    SELECT INITCAP(FNAME || '  '|| LNAME) AS Name, INITCAP(JobTitle), Salary
    FROM (SELECT p.*, AVG(SALARY) OVER () as avg_salary
          FROM FROM PERSON11 p
          WHERE UPPER(CAT) = 'N'
         ) p
    WHERE SALARY >= 1.3 * avg_salary
    ORDER BY LNAME, FNAME ;
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with the window functions - I tried it out of curiosity and I am getting an error - Error at Command Line:3 Column:22
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected" 

I cannot see the reasoning behind the error because I know from comes after the select but I'm a novice at SQL so it might be past my knowledge level

Comment: Why is the GROUP BY necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to "group by" concatenated name, job title and salary? Do you have more than one row per name?

Perhaps it's because you need to compute the average salary and that requires aggregation? You can't do everything in a single SELECT statement in SQL (at least not with simple tools - you seem to be in the early stages of learning and not looking to use window functions).

The "avg salary" needs to come from a subquery. Where you have `>= 1.3 * round(...)` you should have instead:

```
... >= 1.3 * (select avg(salary) from person11 where cat = 'N')
```

Note that the subquery must be enclosed in parentheses. In your code I see you use `upper(cat)` - is there a concern that cat may be upper or lower case? In that case it may be better to write

```
cat in ('n', 'N')
```

Avoid wrapping column values inside functions whenever possible (that often leads to worse performance). Also, I see no need to round the average salary in your requirements - and in any case, what's the point to rounding to zero decimal places if you then multiply by 1.3? Rounding may actually lead to incorrect output.

EDIT:  Sorry, to clarify: I think you are well on your way already. Use the subquery for the average salary, remove the group by (which doesn't hurt anything but is really unneeded), and if you care to, change the upper(cat) as I suggested; I think your query will work with these changes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I've gotten the hang of it. I really didn't need the group by all along and I was overcomplicating things....